# Как узнать сумму длительности аудиозаписей в файлах?

Tags: python, аудио, wav

Есть папка со множеством вложенных папок с небольшими кусочками аудио. Нужно узнать суммарную длительность.

Можно ли с помощью кода, например, пройти по всем файлам и сложить их длительность? Какие библиотеки/функции использовать?

Comment: Аудио бывает разных формат, для этого могут потребоваться разные библиотеки. Найти ту/те, что нужны для вашей задачи, чтобы они могли возвращать длительность, использовать при переборе всех файлов

Comment: все аудио в формате wav @gil9red

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Непроверенный пример:

```
from pathlib import Path
from librosa import get_duration  #  pip install librosa

wav_dir = Path("/path/to/wave_files")

res = sum(get_duration(filename=str(f)) for f in wav_dir.rglob("*.wav"))
print(res)
```

Comment: Похоже на правду :)

Answer (score 0):

Эта утилита может не соответствовать меткам, так как написана на языке JavaScript. К тому же, все аудиофайлы дожны быть в одной папке. Создайте в этой же папке новый текстовый документ и назовите его, скажем, utilita.html и впишите туда такой код:

```html
<html>
<body bgcolor=#ccc><center><h3>Утилита для определения сумарной длительности звучания</h3>
<div id=vybor>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="myfile" onchange="mysum(this.files)">
</div><br>
<div id = resultat></div>
<script>
function mysum(e){
    resultat.innerHTML = "подождите ...";
    let  b = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i ++){
        let a = new Audio(e[i].name);
        a.onloadedMetaData = (function(){
            b += a.duration; 
            resultat.innerHTML = "Сумарная длительность звучания всех выбранных МП3-файлов: <b>" + Math.round(b / 60) + "</b> минут";
        };
    }
}
vybor.innerHTML = vybor.innerHTML;
</script>
<center></body>
</html>
```

После сохранения перетащите мышью этот файл в новое окно браузера. На странице появится кнопка "выберите файлы". Выделите все аудиофайлы в этой папке и нажмите "выбрать". Результат увидите. Если вдруг вместо числа минут выскочит NaN, то попробуйте ещё раз. Даже если выберите не все аудиофайлы из папки, то подсчитается сумарная длительность звучания только выбранных файлов.